# Apache does not work on website other than localhost

Tags: apache, virtualhost

The VirtualHost file only works in the localhost user and not in any ip at all, be it public, private or self. Here is the VirtualHost file content that's put in the `sites-enabled` folder:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin root@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/matecat/cattool
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm index.shtml
    <Directory /home/matecat/cattool/>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All

       <IfVersion < 2.4>
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all
       </IfVersion>
       <IfVersion >= 2.4>
               Require all granted
       </IfVersion>

        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 hour"
        ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 week"
    </Directory>
    php_flag register_globals off
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_admin_flag short_open_tag on
    php_value memory_limit 1024M
    php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
    php_value post_max_size 200M
    LogLevel error
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/matecat.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/matecat.log combined
    ServerSignature Off

    # Configuration for Nodejs proxy
    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location /sse/ >
      ProxyPass http://0.0.0.0:7788/
      ProxyPassReverse http://0.0.0.0:7788/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I commented out the lines:

```
Servername localhost
ServerAdmin root@localhost
```

but it still doesn't work bys using the "IPv4" of the of the system after restarting the apache server.

Comment: Have you checked your firewall settings?

Comment: Is this the only VirtualHost in your Apache?

Comment: @Nic3500 Another is the default configuration Vhost file. That's the one which opens when I use the IP.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig It's listening on port 80: `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27526/apache2   `

Comment: If you do not specify a domain, and access it via IP, Apache will use the first VirtualHost it finds that matches, top down.  Here, any IP (*), port 80.  So if the default configuration VirtualHost is not commented out, Apache will use this default config.  So comment out the default one, or move yours over the default one.  But no one needs that default config anyway :-)

Comment: @Nic3500 yeah after disabling the default config, its working now.

Comment: Great!  I changed my comment into an answer, I would appreciate you approve it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not specify a domain, and access it via IP, Apache will use the first VirtualHost it finds that matches, top down.

Here, any IP (*), port 80. So if the default configuration VirtualHost is not commented out, Apache will use this default config. So comment out the default one, or move yours over the default one. But no one needs that default config anyway :-)